# Unable to populate dynamic dropdown in angular ui grid

Tags: angularjs, user-interface, drop-down-menu, grid

I'm working on a project where I'm trying to add a dropdown in a UI Grid and the values of those dropdowns should come directly from the database. How can i implement this functionality?

Comment: Take a .ts class to hold data from database and iterate in html form using *ngFor. it will work fine. more info https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf

Comment: I'm sorry, but i need this in angular js and the drop down should be available in UI Grid